# Rstudio very slow when editing large code

Tags: r, performance, rstudio

RStudio is working well in general (v 2021.09.1 Build 372).
But when a large code (7000 lines, a collection of functions) is being edited, even a click on the text or unfolding takes about 4 seconds to respond.
I've tried to disable diagnostics, but the problem still occurs.
Is there any setup that can help?

Answer (score 5):

It seems that disabling "use real-time spell-checking" solve the problem.
Before, I've  tried other solutions, like disabling "Diagnostics", without results.
Besides, to avoid the slow debugging of that big file, when debug is needed, specific functions are copied to a temp.R and then "debugSourced"

Comment: I'm glad that helped. A better long term solution would be to split your code into multiple files. There is nothing that should require 7000 lines for a single file.

Comment: @Dason, this file is sourced at RStudio startup and has the functions I develop for my work (ML, SQL, etc.)

Comment: I mean... ok. But you could split that up into multiple files.  Nothing you said changes that.  It sounds like you should turn those functions into a package where each function is in each of their own files.  And you won't have any issues modifying those files in RStudio.